# Valgrind flags, debug vs release compilation

Tags: c++, build, cmake, valgrind

On a Jenkins instance, I need Valgrind to check if there are particular problems in a C++ compiled binary. However, I only need a yes / no answer, not a stack trace for example. If they are any problems, I will launch valgrind on the faulty code with debug flags activated on my personal machine. The build is managed with CMake on a Linux running machine (targeting gcc).

If I compile my code with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` on the Jenkins instance, will Valgrind detect the same problems in the binary as with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind works by instrumenting and replacing parts of your code at runtime, like redirecting calls to memory allocation functions. For doing this it does not rely on debug information, but it might get confused by optimized code:

> If you are planning to use Memcheck: On rare occasions, compiler
>   optimisations (at -O2 and above, and sometimes -O1) have been observed
>   to generate code which fools Memcheck into wrongly reporting
>   uninitialised value errors, or missing uninitialised value errors. We
>   have looked in detail into fixing this, and unfortunately the result
>   is that doing so would give a further significant slowdown in what is
>   already a slow tool. So the best solution is to turn off optimisation
>   altogether.
>   (from the [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.started))

Since the `Release` build type is uses optimizations, that makes it a bad fit for your case.